# How to set a Slack Reminder with Slack Reminder API to a channel?

Tags: javascript, slack-api

The current [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add) for Reminders allows developers to create a reminder for a specific person. This reminder is directly messaged to them via Slackbot; however, I want the reminder to be posted in a public channel. The Reminder API does not specify a channel argument so I'm unsure how to accomplish this with their API. I've posted my current code to create a reminder for a specific user below as reference.

**Slack Reminder to user**

```
var payload = {
    "token": settings.slackToken,
    "text": text,
    "time": time,
    "user": user
};

var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': payload
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(settings.slackRemindersURL, options);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same question about a month ago. When I asked slack support, this was their answer:

> It's not currently possible to use the API to set a channel reminder. However, it's an interesting idea and one we've had from other developers too. I've shared your thoughts with the Platform team for consideration in a future release.

Sorry for being the bearer of bad news. But maybe if you email them as well, they will know it is a needed feature.

Comment: Thank you for the pasted email response. I sent them an email request as well. Hopefully this is a feature they will include soon

Answer (score 0):

There is a new API [scheduleMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage), which can schedule message into a channel.

For example:

```py
app.client.chat_scheduleMessage(channel=<channel_id>, text=<content>, post_at=<timestamp>)
```

However It can not handle recurring message successfully, you can use other tools to trigger the function.